How to atomically update a document with a lock condition in MongoDB/Mongoose and distinguish between not found due to lock vs. document nonexistence?
I'm using Mongoose to manage a MongoDB collection that includes embedded documents representing transactions. I need to ensure that I can atomically update the "lock" field of a document based on specific conditions.
The requirements are:

The document should only be updated if it doesn't already have an exclusive lock ('X') in any of the transactions.
The document should only be updated if the timestamp of the transactions is older than 5 minutes, to prevent deadlocks.
If the document meets these conditions, I want to set an exclusive lock ('X') on it so that I can safely manipulate the files in the directory.

The problem is that I need to distinguish whether the document was not found due to:

The document not meeting the lock condition.
The document simply not existing.

How can I achieve this in an atomic way, ensuring that only one operation happens at a time and correctly handles the lock condition? Any guidance or improvements on the code would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the example code:
// Schemas
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;

const TransactionSchema = new Schema(
  {
    timestamp: { type: Number, required: true },
    lock: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const DirectorySchema = new Schema(
  {
    owner: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
    transactions: [TransactionSchema],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const DirectoryModel = model('Directory', DirectorySchema);

// Example function
const updateLock = async (req) => {
  const initTransaction = {
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    lock: 'X', // exclusive lock
  };

  try {
    // Check the directory status, if the directory is not busy, then set the exclusive lock
    const doc = await DirectoryModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        owner: req.uid,
        _id: req.params.id,
        'transactions.lock': { $ne: 'X' }, // check there are no Exclusive lock in the transactions
        'transactions.timestamp': { $lte: Date.now() - 300000 }, // prevent deadlock
      },
      {
        $push: { transactions: initTransaction }
      },
      {
        returnOriginal: false,
        upsert: false // ensure it doesn't insert a new document if not found
      }
    ).exec();

    if (!doc) {
      console.log('Document not found or lock condition not met');
    } else {
      // Manipulate the file in the directory
      // do something...
      console.log('Document updated:', doc);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating lock:', error);
  }
};

// Example request object
const req = {
  uid: 'user123',
  params: { id: 'documentId123' }
};

// Call the function
updateLock(req);

I need to ensure that the operation is atomic to prevent race conditions and correctly distinguish between the document not being found due to the lock condition vs. the document not existing. How can I achieve this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I end up the way below: Step 1, check the doc existance; Step 2, check the lock condition and update to 'locked'. It is not atomic between Step 1 and Step 2.

Sorry for not making the following point explicit. The four distinct steps in process 1 is part of our discussion about the things under the hood. Its implementation is to do using findOneAndUpdate and upsert true. It means the four steps will be performed by the single method call. And then it becomes atomic. Similarly the whole discussion in process 2 is to implement with a single call of findOneAndDelete.

Another more simplified and straight approach is there to discuss with you but it has a prerequisite. Therefore let us first confirm that. Is there any master collection of  the documents which we are trying to lock and unlock? if yes,  and if possible, please share its schema, only the relevant keys.

Please be informed, when you make a comment in a Question, it would be automatically notified to the creator, and also to those explicitly set to Follow the same question. However when you comment to another commenter in a post, that commenter will not be notified automatically since there is no way your comment is connected to him/her. Therefore you need to address him explicitly address him. For example, when you make a comment in this post, since I am not Following this post, if I need to be notified of your comment, i must be explicitly addressed as @wedothebest4you

The issue over here is there are three possibilities as :

The document may not be existing there in the directory
The document may be existing in the directory but in locked state
The document may be existing in the directory but in unlocked state

The update method findOneAndUpdate can do only two operations in an atomic way. It is to note that it cannot do the "three operations" mentioned above in an atomic manner.

It can find the document
and update it or insert new if the document is not existing

Therefore to review the approach as how can we leverage these two operations only and get the document locked and unlocked.
Consider the process as a whole - both locking and unlocking. One of the revised approaches may be as written below.
Process 1: Locking the document

Using findOneAndUpdate, try to find the document first. The query document of this query needs to have only user id and document id.
If it finds, it means the document is already in locked state.
If it does not find, then insert a new document, this newly inserted document represents the new locked status.
The update document of this query can have all other details to store.

Process 2: Unlocking the document

Using findOneAndDelete, find and delete the document.
Again, the update document can be only on the user Id and the document id.
Once deleted, the document is in unlocked status.

By this way, the locking and unlocking of documents will be atomic.
The data deleted needs to be logged for future reference, this may need to be done after the deletion through a post middleware or coded locally.

Thanks to Voters. Request if possible, please leave a comment as well, I am willing to improve this post as you may suggest.

We've already been over this. How does this (wall-of-text) actually answer the question?

Thank you for your care and time. I have been keeping your advice to be specific on answering. It has been guiding and helping me all the while. Still at times the old self will come out. Please bear me now, I shall try again to be adhered to your guidance. And do intervene and correct me whenever you may find it is needed. Thanking you once again.
